# Is it bad practice to create setter and getters to simplify functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

**Example:**

I'm working on a user interface for a robotics project that displays the wheel calibration ratio. The default ratio is 0.89 and I have a button that increments the ratio by 0.01.

```
function incrementRatio() {
    if (getStatus() != "Connected" || getRatio() >= 1.00) {
        stopEvent();
    } else {
        var newRatio = getRatio() + 0.01;

        setUIArrayValue("currentRatio", newRatio);
        setIDText('ratiovalue', getRatio().toFixed(2));
    }
}
```

The function above uses getters and setters such as:

- getStatus(), getRatio()
- setUIArrayValue(key, value), setIDText(id, text)

Some of these contain one statement but are frequently re-used throughout the code.

For instance, `setIDText()`:

```
function setIDText(id, text) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}
```

Contains 1 statement, but provides a much shorter and readable way of mutating text. Without these setters and getters, functions such as incrementRatio() would look fairly cluttered.

Comment: Are you talking about actual getters and setters, or just something you like to call "getters" and "setters"? Why not post the function that contains these getters and setters? Creating regular functions that does things to simplify, is just fine BTW

Comment: I would not call them getters/setters, as that usually refers to properties; but yes putting frequently used functionality in reusable functions is a very good and standard practice.

Comment: Sorry, I guess they're just something I called getters and setters. What I really sought to know is if it's "bad" to create functions that group frequently used statements/make code easier to read.

Comment: The answer is: no, getters and setters are not bad practice, per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you name getters and setters are not really as these perform real logic as for example the `setIDText()` function :

```
function setIDText(id, text) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
}
```

These are rather helper/logic methods that allows both :

- to avoid repeating yourself.
- to make your code more readable and straight understandable by abstracting implementation details in a function that conveys an explicit naming.

Using this kind of function is a good thing as it provides a better quality code.

Comment: What, you don't enjoy [**W**riting **E**verything **T**wice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions)?

Comment: @Patrick Roberts Not really but touching twice my wage, why not :)

Answer (score 0):

No it isnt. It makes the code much more readable, and a good parser will inline it so the performance difference might be close to zero.

Comment: No, it does much more than just parsing. A parser simply generates AST, a compiler generates executable code, and in v8, it also implements some pretty advanced optimization techniques, which is why JavaScript has slowly managed to have more performance capability over the years.